# inner join and echo solution

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an inner join of three tables:

```
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT singleimageupload.codrif AS codrif,
       singleimageupload.imagesname AS bigimage,
       uploads.imagesname AS multipleimage,
       uploads.description AS multipledescription,
       exposition.name,
       exposition.author,
       exposition.description,
       exposition.misure,
       exposition.date,
       exposition.status
  FROM exposition
 INNER JOIN singleimageupload ON singleimageupload.codrif = exposition.codrif
 INNER JOIN uploads ON uploads.codrif = exposition.codrif
 WHERE singleimageupload.firstimage = 'first' AND exposition.codrif = 'A002'
 ORDER BY exposition.codrif");
```

and I get this result:
[image]

I have, with this conditions, a result for each uploads path that I have.

My goal is to get something like this: 
[image]

So, I would like to merge all uploads path for their Cod Rif (in this example, A002).

This is my full code:

```
  <?php



include('guestconfig/config.php');



$result=mysql_query("SELECT singleimageupload.codrif AS codrif,
       singleimageupload.imagesname AS bigimage,
       uploads.imagesname AS multipleimage,
       uploads.description AS multipledescription,
       exposition.name,
       exposition.author,
       exposition.description,
       exposition.misure,
       exposition.date,
       exposition.status
  FROM exposition
 INNER JOIN singleimageupload ON singleimageupload.codrif = exposition.codrif
 INNER JOIN uploads ON uploads.codrif = exposition.codrif
 WHERE singleimageupload.firstimage = 'first' AND exposition.codrif = 'A002'
 ORDER BY exposition.codrif");




while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {


?>
<table border="0">

<tr>
<td> <?php echo $row['codrif']?> </td>
</tr>
<tr>

<td> <?php echo $row['bigimage']?> </td>
</tr>
<tr>

<td> <?php echo $row['name']?> </td>
</tr>
<tr>

<td> <?php echo $row['author']?> </td>
</tr>
<tr>

<td> <?php echo $row['multipledescription']?> </td>

</tr>
<hr>
</table>

<?php } ?>
```

I don't know if I explained it clear, I hope so

Comment: **Warning** do **not** use `mysql_*` functions, they're deprecated and are removed in the newest version of PHP. You are also open to mysql injection, you should look into prepared statements, but you'll have to change library first to do so. Those `mysql_*` functions are from the 90's, keep them there, please.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I will study new libraries and change mysql statement.

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to mention those library names. I would advise for either `PDO` or `mysqli`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using group_concat(uploads.description) and group by singleimageupload.codrif

Comment: It's working, but how Can I use echo for each concat data? Thanks

Comment: THE GROUP_CONCAT data will be coming as string, explode using ,(comma).

Comment: ok, but how can I use single data into an echo? something like echo $row['multipledescription'][0]
echo $row['multipledescription'][1] ? Sorry but I really don't know how I can do it. Thanks

Comment: use like group_concat(uploads.description) as multiuploads and then, $uploads = explode(',',$multiuploads);

$uploads[0]
$uploads[1]

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I also tried this solution and it works too: list($images1, $images2, $images3, $images4, $images5) = explode(',', $row['multipledescription']);
Thanks again!